# Calculating angle a segment forms with a ray

Tags: geometry, angles

I am given a point C and a ray r starting there. I know the coordinates (xc, yc) of the point C and the angle theta the ray r forms with the horizontal, theta in (-pi, pi]. I am also given another point P of which I know the coordinates (xp, yp): how do I calculate the angle alpha that the segment CP forms with the ray r, alpha in (-pi, pi]?

Some examples follow:
[image: example 1]
[image: example 2]
[image: example 3]

I can use the the atan2 function.

Comment: This quedtion would probably better housed in the mathematics-SE?

Comment: "I can use the `atan2` function" OK, so, what's the problem then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No conditions, you don't need normalised vectors, a single trig function:

```
Vector2 pc = p - c;
float crossp = pc.x * ray.direction.y - pc.y * ray.direction.x;
float dotp = pc.x * ray.direction.x + pc.y * ray.direction.y;
return Math.atan2(crossp, dotp);
```

Here is the [explanation](http://johnblackburne.blogspot.com.br/2012/01/angle-between-two-vectors.html). A fast summary:

- Cross product between two vectors is the same as `sin(theta) * len(v1) * len(v2)`
- Dot product between two vectors is the same as `cos(theta) * len(v1) * len(v2)`
- Since `atan2` requires two variables (the y and the x component), it already outputs detailed info (an angle on the ]-pi, +pi] range, so it gives sense of direction too)
- `atan2(y, x)` is simply `atan(y / x)`, if you put the entire formula, `atan((sin * len1 * len2) / (cos * len1 * len2))` you see that len1 and len2 cancel themselves, so we're just with `atan(sin / cos)`. Since sin represents the vertical component of a triangle and cos represents the horizontal component of a triangle, everything goes well, no need to take a single `sqrt` and no need to use conditionals to change the range.

Answer (score 1):

We  find the vector from c to p (p - c), and compute its angle with the x-axis. Then we subtract, and put it into the right range.

```
theta2 = atan2(p_x - c_x, p_y - c_y)
alpha = theta2-theta
if (alpha > pi) alpha -= 2pi
if (alpha <= -pi) alpha += 2pi
```

This assumes that theta is in the range (-pi, pi], and atan2 gives its result in the range (-pi, pi] as well. Otherwise you can just make those while loops.

Note this is a signed angle, not an absolute one.

Comment: I took some time to experiment.  
According to The correct formula appears to be as follows:  
`theta2 = atan2(p_y - c_y, p_x - c_x)`  
and not  
`theta2 = atan2(p_x - c_x, p_y - c_y)`

Comment: Ah, there are differing conventions on the order of the arguments to atan2, as it is effectively arctan(y/x) with division by zero handled properly, but is it atan2(x,y) or atan2(y,x)? Different libraries make different choices.